# Android - Delay in closing activity with VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have an Activity with a VideoView -- that loads a video from the web. However, when the user clicks the back button before the video has fully loaded, the screen goes black and several seconds pass before it returns to the previous activity. Is there a way to force the VideoView to quit more quickly?

Here is the code for setting up the stream. The URL for the video is passed in the Intent:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {
  ...

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(videoPreparedListener);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(videoErrorListener);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(<myvideourl>);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);

  }
  …

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually need to stop the video, before the activity is finished. Otherwise you can even end up getting IllegalStateException in case you rotate your device and you've chosen in your manifest file that the activity is recreated upon device's rotation. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  mVideoView.stopPlayback();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it still doesn't prevent a long delay in returning to the previous activity. Anything else I could be missing? I don't seem to be able to call release() the way you do on a MediaPlayer -- is there an equivalent on the VideoView? I also tried adding mVideoView.suspend() to onPause() and that also didn't help. I'm wondering if the connection to get the stream is not releasing and is bottlenecking the app...

Comment: @bkurzius what's the video player is using in your project?

Comment: @TiagoBarreto -- This post was from 2011 so I would use Exoplayer now: Exoplayerhttps://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue ,did you get any solution